# TIPA: suppress tonestembar no longer works in fontspec

Tags: xetex, fontspec, tipa

Most of the features in tipa from TeXLive2009 seem to be part of fontspec in TeXLive2012 -- if you activate both, you get an error message: "Command sups already defined".

The following code to suppress the side tonestembars on tone letters worked fine with tipa in TeXLive2009, but no longer works with fontspec in TeXLive2012:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@tonestembar{%
  \setbox0\hbox{\tipaencoding\char'277}%
  \hbox{\vrule height \ht0 depth \dp0
      width 0pt}}
\makeatother
```

You get an error that tonestembar is undefined, and the tonemarks are printed with the sidebar attached.

Is there any way of tweaking this code to persuade TeXLive2012 to suppress the tonestembars?

**MWE latex (works):**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, oneside]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage[tone]{tipa}  %  tone invokes the tone letters
% Fix tonemarks to show marks without sidebars.
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@tonestembar{%
  \setbox0\hbox{\tipaencoding\char'277}%
  \hbox{\vrule height \ht0 depth \dp0 width 0pt}} % no stem
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is an example of the tonemarks without the stembars:

\textbf{babubibuba [~\tone{11}\, \tone{55}\, \tone{33}\, \tone{55}\, \tone{11}~]}

\end{document}
```

**MWE xetex (doesn't work):**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, oneside]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text, Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}

% \usepackage[tone]{tipa}  % IPA letters - tone invokes the tone letters
% Fix tonemarks to show marks without sidebars.
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@tonestembar{%
  \setbox0\hbox{\tipaencoding\char'277}%
  \hbox{\vrule height \ht0 depth \dp0 width 0pt}} % no stem
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\fontspec[Renderer=Graphite]{Charis SIL}

This is an example of the tonemarks which are showing the stembars in spite of using the suppression code that works in latex:

\textbf{babubibuba [~\tone{11}\, \tone{55}\, \tone{33}\, \tone{55}\, \tone{11}~]}

Changing ``renewcommand'' to ``newcommand'' to get rid of the error message``@tonestembar undefined'' makes no difference.

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Since this code isn't documented in the TIPA manual it would be helpful to post a minimal document that shows what it does with `pdflatex` so that we can see the effect that needs to be implemented in with the `xunicode` version (the work is done by the `xunicode` package, not actually by `fontspec`.)

Comment: It would also be helpful to show a XeTeX document which uses the tones (with the tonestembars).

Comment: Sorry, MWEs now added.

Comment: Thanks for the examples. Because the tone characters are now implemented as real Unicode combining characters, the bar is an integral part of the glyph, and Unicode doesn't seem to have included ones without the bar (since they are not IPA).  So to do this you'll need some sort of a hack, as far as I can tell.

Comment: OK.  Thanks for this.  So even though they're combining characters, it's possible to "de-combine" them?  It's unfortunate that only the +tonestembar glyphs are in Unicode, because tonestembars are not used in (for instance) African linguistics.

Answer (score 5):

The support for `tipa` input provided by `fontspec` comes from the `xunicode` package. However, it does not cover everything that `tipa` can do. A work-around is to prevent `xuicode` loading:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, oneside]{article}
\expandafter\def\csname ver@xunicode.sty\endcsname{}
\usepackage[tone]{tipa}  %  tone invokes the tone letters
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text, Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}

% \usepackage[tone]{tipa}  % IPA letters - tone invokes the tone letters
% Fix tonemarks to show marks without sidebars.
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@tonestembar{%
  \setbox0\hbox{\tipaencoding\char'277}%
  \hbox{\vrule height \ht0 depth \dp0 width 0pt}} % no stem
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\fontspec[Renderer=Graphite]{Charis SIL}

This is an example of the tonemarks which are showing the stembars in spite of using the suppression code that works in latex:

\textbf{babubibuba [~\tone{11}\, \tone{55}\, \tone{33}\, \tone{55}\, \tone{11}~]}

Changing ``renewcommand'' to ``newcommand'' to get rid of the error message``@tonestembar undefined'' makes no difference.

\end{document}
```

although of course if the real document uses other `xuincode` features this will be an issue!