# TIPA tone bar glyph missing with xeCJK

Tags: fonts, xetex, xecjk, tipa

Using XeLaTeX, this piece of code produces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tone]{tipa}
\begin{document}
    \textipa{
    j\textturna u\tone{12}
    }
\end{document}
```

[image: tex1]

However, the the tone bar is broken when `xeCJK` package is added in:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tone]{tipa}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\begin{document}
    \textipa{
    j\textturna u\tone{12}
    }
\end{document}
```

[image: tex2]

and a warning message is given:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T3/lmr/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T3/cmr/m/n' instead
(Font)              for symbol `textturna' on input line 21.

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

Adding in `inputenc` or `fontenc` does not seem to fix this problem. I think there is a font conflict but I am not sure how to restore the "original" `tipa` font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xeCJK loads xunicode and xunicode overwrites all the tipa definition. So you can't use tipa together with xeCJK package. You will have to use the definitions of xunicode and -- as the default font don't show your symbols -- search for a suitable font. Suppressing xunicode as in this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127564/2388 is imho with xeCJK not an option.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\newfontfamily\mytipafont{Doulos SIL}
\def\useTIPAfont{\mytipafont}

\begin{document}
    \textipa{j\textturna u\tone{12}}
\end{document}
```

[image]